# jQuery each method does not return value

Tags: jquery, methods, each

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#commentForm').submit(function(){

        return $('input[type=text], textarea').each(function(index){

            if($(this).attr('value') == ""){
                alert(msgHash[$(this).attr('id')]);
                return false;

            }else{

                if(!$(this).attr('value').match(validateHash[$(this).attr('id')])){
                    //Do nothing
                    alert(msgOnError[$(this).attr('id')]);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        return true;
    });
});
```

Here msgOnError, msgHash and msgHash are map that I use to get messages for each text box with particular ID
Unfortunately each method does not return false to cancel submission of the form. What am I doing wrong ?? I am new to jQuery, Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly how `each` works. Since it's actually a loop that calls your anonymous function in each iteration, exiting those functions, will not exit the calling function as well. Returning true and false here, is actually corresponding to the  `continue` and `break` of the for loop, repsectively.

You're gonna need to set a boolean flag, then return false (break), and then return the value of your boolean flag after the `each`

Comment: That' s true David. I got it working by simply setting a boolean variable in the $('input[type=text], textarea').each method and also removed return keyword. Later inside the $('#commentForm') I checked the boolean and decide whether form should be submitted. Works well.
Thanks again David..

Comment: i'm glad you got things working. if you're happy with a repsonse, you can tick the accept button for that answer, to mark it as the accepted answer. this shows other users know that the question has been resolved.