# javascript doesn't correctly return from the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery each method does not return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900172/jquery-each-method-does-not-return-value)

It seems the return statement does not break the loop and return the function. The following code keeps return false....

```
var __in__ = function(elem, array){
    // $.each(array, function(index, item) {  
   array.forEach(function(index, item) {
        if (item == elem)
            return true;
    });
    return false;
};


console.log(__in__(3,[1,2,3]));
```

Comment: Returning from the expression won't terminate the loop.

Comment: `$.` is not [javascript] but seem to by [jquery].

Comment: But even i use forEach is the same. that means forEach in ES5 does the same thing?

Comment: You have, essentially, `function(){ return true; }` in both cases -- it returns from the anonymous function, not from the one that called it!

Comment: @Lkahtz How about `jQuery.grep()` ?

Comment: This is probably just an example function, but there's also [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Comment: Thanks, JohnDoe & Juhana, I really need to go through jQuery's API thoroughly.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Initialy, there was only `javascript` tag on this question. And definitively no. jQuery is no Javascript. jQuery is a higher level language based on Javascript, but it's no javascript.

Comment: @F.Hauri , please tell me that you are joking. Please !?

Comment: @tereško No: `$.each` (in this case) is a `jQuery` function and not *pure javascript*. Try other frameworks like `mootool` or `qooxdoo` and you will see other implementations... Saying that `jQuery` is `javascript` is like saying that `C` is `assembler`.

Comment: @F.Hauri jQuery is just a bunch of JavaScript functions, look at the [**source**](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js).

Comment: @F.Hauri "Better to remain silent and be thought a fool than to speak out and remove all doubt in the end" - Licoln. Of course jQ is Javascript...

Comment: @Jasper @tereško @Nile  Ok, it's javascript... But at all `each: function(` is a `jQuery` function which is implemented in different way by `mootools` and others...(framework, bunch, sdk...) So this question is not a `javascript` concern, but really a `jQuery` specific concern. *bunch of JavaScript functions* or *higher framwork language* there is a subtil bound... (Remember: first only the javascript tag was tagging this question, it was the reason why I wrote: *$. is not [javascript] but seem to be [jquery]* ``seem'' because `$` is used in many other *bunch of javascript functions*.

Answer (score 11):

That is because `$.each` it is executing function callbacks. `$.each` is not a `for` loop. The following is what you're after:

```
var __in__ = function(elem, array){
    var result = false;

    $.each(array, function(index, item) {
        if (item == elem) {
            result = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    return result;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/unByH/1/

Answer (score 4):

Your inner return statement only returns from the inner (nested) function, the outer return statement is always running (even on a match).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var __in__ = function(elem, array){
    var found = false;

    $.each(array, function(index, item) {
        if (item == elem) {
            found = true;
            return false; // break out of $.each call
        }
    });

    return found;
};
```

Comment: When I started typing there was no complete answer yet. Also, it is not **mandatory** to return from the `each` call but I agree that, performance-wise, it **should** be done, so I'll fix it.