# Return a value from a nested each function

Tags: jquery, nested-function

I'm trying to get the hash of a url and compare it to a list of href's in a list. Below is the relevant portion of my code

```
                //ON PAGE LOAD
                var hash = document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1);
            hash = '#' + hash;
            if(hash)
            {
                $( "#tab ul li a" ).each(function( index ) {
                  if(hash==$(this).attr('href'))
                  {
                    alert(index);
                    return index;
                  }
                });
            }
            alert(index);
            //DO STUFF WITH INDEX
```

The problem is that the nested function isn't returning the index value (its definitely being set). The first alert is returning a number - the second however is returning undefined.

How do I go about returning the index of the matched value?

Comment: Where do you want it to return to? If it returns from the containing function, it will skip over the "DO STUFF WITH INDEX" code.

Comment: It's part of how jquery's `each()` works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900172/jquery-each-method-does-not-return-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return stuff in the middle of your `each`. At most you can return `false` to break the loop. Use a placeholder variable to store the value you want and then break the loop.

```
            var returnValue;
            $( "#tab ul li a" ).each(function( index ) {
              if(hash==$(this).attr('href'))
              {
                alert(index);
                returnValue = index;
                return false; // breaks the each
              }
            });
```

when you do `...each(function(...` you are creating a function that will be called inside the `each`. So if you return something in it, the return value will be read somewhere inside the `each` code, which will keep executing and return something else (normaly another jQuery object to allow chainability). The `each` actually expects you to return something if you want. And that is for example `false` so that it stops iterating through the list of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You should store it in a variable which is defined before the loop, then return `false` to stop the loop. (`each`'s return value is only used to determine whether the loop should stop early)

Example:

```
var returned;
$( "#tab ul li a" ).each(function( index ) {
    if(hash==$(this).attr('href')) {
        returned = index;
        return false;
    }
});
// returned contains the value, or undefined
```